# tables rmarkdown cellpadding

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to make a table using either hwrite or xtable in rmarkdown to produce a html table. I have been unable to use a cellpadding or cellspacing option, this is the code I am using and attached is a photo of the output.

```
{r, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}

cat(hwrite(sd.m.table, row.names = FALSE, cellpadding = 10, row.style = list("font-weight:bold")))
```

Using xtable() similarly did not work as well. Does anyone have suggestions?

[Generated output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgUTc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `hwriter` package, and I rarely use `xtable` anymore (because I get frustrated with customizing tables), so I can't give you specific advice on using those.

I'm most comfortable with `pixiedust` (because I wrote it), but the `htmlTable` and `tableHTML` packages produce nice HTML tables and are probably worth looking into as well.

Working example with `pixiedust`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(pixiedust)

head(mtcars) %>%
  dust() %>%
  sprinkle(pad = 10) %>%
  medley_all_borders()
```
````

### EDIT:

To get the appearance you are seeking with your data, try using

```
library(pixiedust)
library(dplyr)


DF <- 
  data.frame(rep_complete_time = c("2017-01-04 08:58:22",
                                   "2017-01-04 08:58:33",
                                   "2017-01-06 11:35:28"),
             result = c(4.99184, 4.07356, 5.01569),
             body_fluid = c("Serum", "Serum", "Serum"),
             result_type = c("QC", "QC", "QC"),
             fluid_lot = c(4426, 4426, 4426),
             level = c(1, 1, 1))

DF %>%
  # for some reason, sprintf results aren't holding when used in a 
  # sprinkle.  This seems like a bug in pixiedust.
  mutate(result = sprintf("%0.1f", result)) %>%
  dust() %>%
  sprinkle_colnames("Rep Complete Time", "Result", "Body Fluid",
                    "Result Type", "Fluid Lot", "Level") %>%
  # use part = "table" to apply borders to all parts of the table.
  # by default, pixiedust only wants to work with the body of the table.
  medley_all_borders(part = "table") %>%
  # using the sprinkle_table function can apply sprinkles to all of the
  # parts of a table.
  sprinkle_table(pad = 10,
                 halign = "left")
```

I wasn't able to replicate your alignment problem. All of the columns in my results are aligned left.

Comment: This is a very helpful package that I have never heard of before! The only issues I am having now are that not all columns are aligning left like I want even using `sprinkle(halign = "left")`, that I am unable to get a border around the headers and that when a column is rounded to 0.1 and the value is a whole number it shows up as 5 instead of 5.0